# Extract webscraped python data to SQLite, excel or xml?

Tags: python, xml, excel, sqlite

I'm kinda new to Python and webscraping but I'm currently at a point where I need to extract data to a database. Can someone tell me the pros and cons by using sqlite, excel or xml?

I've read that sqlite should be the fastest, so I may go for that database structure, but can someone then tell me what IDE you use to handle sqlite data after I've extracted it from python?

Edit: I hope my post makes sense. I'm currently trying to use a web scraper from here: https://github.com/gingeleski/odds-portal-scraper

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the short term, Excel is a good way to examine your data and prototype analysis and visualizations. It gets old using it for very large datasets, or multiple similar datasets. Basically as soon as you start doing the same thing more than twice or writing VB code you should switch to the pandas/matplotlib solution.

It looks like the scraper you are using already puts the results in an SQLITE database, but if you have your data in a list or dictionary, I'd suggest using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do calculations and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for visualizations, as that will give you a robust, extensible solution over the long term. It is very easy to [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) and [write](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) data between an SQLITE database and pandas.

A good way of viewing the data in the DB is a must. I'm currently using [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt).

Answer (score 0):

When you say IDE, I'm assuming you're looking for a way to view the SQLite data? If so, [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) is a free, open source SQL client. You could use this to view the data quite easily.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to use python to read/edit the .db files data? Is that still possible? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You can edit the db using Python using a number of modules, `sqlite3` works well. The advice given above is good, and I would recommend following it while you're still learning!